# Apache Tomcat Load Balancing Cluster

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing, tomcat8

I am having 3 servers installed with Ubuntu and I want to configure Tomcat Load Balancing.

```
Server A = 10.0.0.1,
Server B = 10.0.0.2,
Server C = 10.0.0.3
```

I have pointed Domain to Server A which is having Apache and Mod_JK installed. while Server B and C is having Apache Tomcat 8. below is the Details of my workers.properties file

> ```
> workers.apache_log=/var/log/apache2 worker.list=tomcatlb,status
> worker.stat1.type=status
>
> worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13 worker.tomcat1.host=10.0.0.2 #put your app
> host here worker.tomcat1.port=8009 worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13 
> worker.tomcat2.host=10.0.0.3 worker.tomcat2.port=8009
>
> worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1  worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1 
>
> worker.tomcatlb.type=lb
> worker.tomcatlb.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2
>
> worker.list=jkstatus worker.jkstatus.type=status
> ```

I have also used jvmRounte name as tomcat1 and tomcat2 in server.xml of both the Apache Tomcat.

i have also added below lines in server.xml

> ```
>       <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
>
>         <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
> channelSendOptions="6"> 
>
>         <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
>         <Membership     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
>         address="228.0.0.4"
>         port="45564" frequency="500"
>         dropTime="3000"/> 
>
>         <Sender     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
>
>         <Transport     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
>
>         </Sender> 
>
>         <Receiver     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
>         address="auto" port="4001" autoBind="100"
>         selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/> 
>
>         <Interceptor     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
>
>         <Interceptor     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interc    eptor"/>
>         <Interceptor     className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
>
>
>         </Channel>
> ```

context.xml is like below

> ```
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
> distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
> WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
> See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
> limitations under the License.
> -->
> <!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
> <Context>
>
> <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the -->
> <!-- web application will be reloaded. -->
> <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
> <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
>
> <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
> <!--
> <Manager pathname="" />
> -->
>
> <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
> on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
> <!--
> <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
> -->
>
> <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
> expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
> notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
> <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager" />
>
> </Context>
> ```

apache configuration is having below lines

> ```
>  RewriteEngine on
>     RewriteRule ^/$ /test [PT,L]
>     JkMount /* tomcatlb
> ```

apache is redirecting the request to Tomcat via mod_jk and its working fine but when one tomcat goes down it should redirect the request to the other tomcat instead of that I have to do relogin as its not replicating the session.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing that you're missing
stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid lbmethod=byrequests nofailover=Off connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: These are actually separate lines:

```
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13 worker.tomcat1.host=10.0.0.2
```

Comment: some how its combined here but in file all lines are on new line

Answer (score 0):

Besides: Is it intentional, that 10.0.0.1 is missing in your worker properties?

Comment: but 10.0.0.1 is not my worker its having apache and mod_jk yet I should mention it in workers.properties? if yes, please let me know how I can do so